# PHP file loading or listing operations not working

Tags: php, windows-10

## Software versions

- **OS:** Windows 10 Pro Version 1903 Build 18362.175
- **PHP:** 7.3.6

## The Problem

So I did update to the newest version of Windows 10 and all the loading/listing file operations like

- glob
- scandir
- file_get_contents

do not work anymore, in the case of glob the returning array is empty while scandir is throwing an error:

```
PHP Warning:  scandir(): Die Datei oder das Verzeichnis ist kein Analysepunkt. (code: 4390) in
```

file_get_contents is throwing cannot read the file content:

```
file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

The operation did work just fine before upgrading to the new os version and the operation still works on another computer with an older OS (Windows 10 Pro Version 1803 Build 17134.829) and PHP Version (7.3.3).

The problem occurs on another machine as well with the same OS Version. This machine did not update php yet and is using version 7.2.9.

The folders are located in a OneDrive sync folder but the files are set to "keep on disk" to prevent any errors with files not present yet.

## Already tried

- Checking if the problem is present on another machine a well
- Searching google for solutions for this problem
- Update the PHP Version it was 7.2.9 before

@edit I did add missing information about the OneDrive

Comment: Try forcing a sync in Onedrive. After that try shutting down Onedrive so it doesn't interfere or lock the files.

Comment: Sadly this is not working but you are right the problem is related to OneDrive I did try to list files from the Downloads folder which is working just fine.


I did suspend OneDrive for testing but the problem is still existing.
I did quit OneDrive but the problem is not fixed so it seems like something with the access rights is broken

Comment: I did run the same code with my Ubuntu WSL with OneDrive closed and the file listing is working. Activating OneDrive and the file sync did not change this result.

Comment: Is it possible not to use the onedrive folder directly? Maybe use rsync to copy the files to a different directory and use this directory for your php project.

Comment: This could work as a workaround for the moment I will give it a try.

Comment: Do you have another workaround other than moving directories ?

Comment: Sadly I did not find another solution just yet. At the moment I'm moving the files to a folder not synced via OneDrive manually or with a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a PHP bug #78220 related to onedrive, it was fixed starting from versions 7.3.10 & 7.2.23

http://bugs.php.net/78220